# I can't get my AspNet project to run in https

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an AspNet, .Net Framework 4.8 project, that was recently updated from 4.6.1 .Net Framework.

While trying to integrate 'Sign In With Microsoft' using OpenIDConnect, I downloaded a Quick Start app from Azure's App Registration, and out of the box this app runs on https://localhost:44368

Both apps have Enable SSL = True. Not sure why the Sample app doesn't have any problem.

Any clues on things to look for? I haven't tested rolling out to our Test Server, but I need to be able to debug also. I can start with an http page and our app starts fine.

Thanks

[Project Url For Sample App vs My App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Fbz.png)

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by "can't get to run"?  Do you mean if you type http it doesn't redirect to https?  Or do you mean if you type https:... it won't show the page?  Also, what do you mean by "Enable SSL = true"?  Do you mean in the project properties?

Comment: Also, what URL does it show for the https url in the project properties sheet?  Is it the same as the url in the properties dialog?  And did you click the "Create virtual directory" button?